# Pushwoosh Device not receiving notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, pushwoosh

Im trying to send a notification to an ios device using the 'devices' parameter on the api object as per documentation. the below json works if i omit the 'devices' parameter but it will go to every device that has the app installed. I just want it to go to the device id i have specified. Im getting the device id using [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor].UUIDString] in objective c. But this device Id doesnt work... any help will be massively appreciated!

```
{
    "request": {
        "application": "xxxxx-xxxxx",
        "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "notifications": [
            {
                "send_date": "now",
                "content": "this is a test",
                "wp_type": "Toast",
                "devices": [
                    "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"
                ],
                "wp_count": 3,
                "data": {
                    "custom": "json data"
                },
                "link": "http://pushwoosh.com/"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The request looks correct. It looks like device UID does not match the device UID in the system. Could you check with the push token instead of device UID?